# nested_scaffold URLGenerationError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, scaffold

My error says:

> No route matches {:action=>"new", :advertiser_id=>"2",
>   :controller=>"analyses", :experiment_id=>nil} missing required keys:
>   [:experiment_id]

Error happens in

> app/views/analyses/index.html.erb:29:in
>   `_app_views_analyses_index_html_erb___267178907_46340268'

Which points to this piece of code in my index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'New Analysis',  new_advertiser_experiment_analysis_path(params[:experiment_id]) %>
```

The error also shows the parameters being passed as:

> Parameters: {"advertiser_id"=>"9", "experiment_id"=>"2"}

Not sure why its telling me it doesnt know the experiment_id.

**Here is my Analyses Controller**

```
class AnalysesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_analyses
  before_action :set_analysis, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  # GET experiments/1/analyses
  def index
    @analyses = @experiment.analyses
  end

  # GET experiments/1/analyses/1
  def show
  end

  # GET experiments/1/analyses/new
  def new
    @analysis = @experiment.analyses.build
  end

  # GET experiments/1/analyses/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST experiments/1/analyses
  def create
    @analysis = @experiment.analyses.build(analysis_params)

    if @analysis.save
      redirect_to([@analysis.experiment, @analysis], notice: 'Analysis was successfully created.')
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  # PUT experiments/1/analyses/1
  def update
    if @analysis.update_attributes(analysis_params)
      redirect_to([@analysis.experiment, @analysis], notice: 'Analysis was successfully updated.')
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

  # DELETE experiments/1/analyses/1
  def destroy
    @analysis.destroy

    redirect_to experiment_analyses_url(@experiment)
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_analyses
      @experiment = Experiment.find(params[:experiment_id])
    end

    def set_analysis
      @analysis = @experiment.analyses.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def analysis_params
      params.require(:analysis).permit(:conversion, :aov, :win_loss, :notes)
    end

end
```

Comment: why you add `_advertiser_`in your view code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your current code it shows that you have three level nesting for resources. e-g:

```
resources :advertiser do 
  resources :experiment do 
  resources :analysis
  end 
end
```

so route `new_advertiser_experiment_analysis_path` expects two ids. one for `advertiser` and other for `experiment` so you are just passing single id which is consider as `advertiser_id` (It follows the order in which we provide id's if not mentioned explicitily by hash) so it get nil for `experiment_id` that's why it fails.
 so you need

```
<%= link_to 'New Analysis',  new_advertiser_experiment_analysis_path(advertiser_id: params[:advertiser_id] , experiment_id: params[:experiment_id]) %>
```

Check [Rails Nested Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) for complete guide.